# The state of qubit after measuring it

Tags: measurements, quantum-measurements

I have a simple question. When a qubit is measured it will collapse into either zero or one state. So how should the notation of the state after measurement be displayed? Is it like classical $0$ or $1$? Or is it $|0\rangle $ or $|1\rangle$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quantum bit (qubit) is still a quantum bit after measuring it. It's not transformed into a classical bit by a measurement. So if you measure a qubit then it will become a |0⟩ or |1⟩. Of course at the end of a quantum calculation the |0⟩ and |1⟩ states are normally associated with classical '0's and '1's for the purpose of reporting the result of the calculation, but that shouldn't be confused with the fact that the qubits themselves end up in the quantum |0⟩ and |1⟩ states.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.